# 60 x 60 image in view

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am trying to place a 60x60 UIImageView into a view using Xamarin Studios iOS designer. The designer is only letting me go as small as 60 x 88. If I open the storyboard into xcode I can get it to 60x60 but then when I go back to the designer its rescaled to 60x88 again.

Is this a bug or is there some restraint I don't know about?

**iOS Designer:**

[image]

**Xcode:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're experiencing the following bug.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20885

It has a workaround listed by Ram Chandra:

> I observed that I am unable to decrease the height of imageview when
>   view controller's "Top bar" property is not set to none. It's default
>   min size is set to 88 and we are not able to decrease the size of
>   Image view less than 88. If we set "Top bar" property to "None" we are
>   able to decrease the size of Image view.